# Multiple linear/non linear transformations in Manim

Tags: python, manim

I'm writing a script in [manim](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim) to perform some transformations. And I want to apply multiple linear/non linear transformations in a sequence to a graph. And I tried it but failed. Here is my code

```py
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class transformation(LinearTransformationScene):
    def construct(self):
        # Linear transformation
        self.apply_matrix([[1, 0], [1, 1]])              # <============

        # Non-linear transformation
        self.apply_nonlinear_transformation(self.func)   # <============

        self.wait()

    def func(self, dot):
        return np.array((max(dot[0], 0), max(dot[1], 0), dot[2]))
```

And there is a strange behavior which I'm unable to understand is that if I run only one of the highlighted lines. Then that transformation works fine. But if I run both lines at the same time then it throughs this error:

```py
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) (200,3)
```

So what is the reason of this error? And how to run both transformations?

Comment: Do you want to apply multiple transformations simultaneously or one after the other?

Comment: After one another

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/eP6oGLcy8L4) does these kind of transformations and the source code is available [here](https://github.com/abhi3019/manim-projects/blob/main/pragyaan/composite_matrix_determinant.py)

Comment: @AbhinavPB Can you point out the code where some transformation code is?

Comment: Add `self.wait()` between the transformations. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69740599/16444630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `self.wait()` between the transformations.

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class transformation(LinearTransformationScene):
    def construct(self):
        # Linear transformation
        self.apply_matrix([[1, 0], [1, 1]])              # <============

         self.wait(0) #just add this

        # Non-linear transformation
        self.apply_nonlinear_transformation(self.func)   # <============

        self.wait()

    def func(self, dot):
        return np.array((max(dot[0], 0), max(dot[1], 0), dot[2]))
```

edit: changed `self.wait()` to `self.wait(0)`

Comment: Ok, using `wait()` its working fine but why this is required? What if I don't require delay between animations?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect this is because `wait()` somehow registers the state of the matrix which is required for applying the next matrix. If you don't want a delay you can use `self.wait(0)`

Comment: I would appreciate if you marked this as the accepted answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: When running this, I'm getting: "TypeError: All submobjects must be of type VMobject".

edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72454358/18114046

Comment: @paoloose Yeah, I am getting the same error now. must be a recent bug.