# How do I apply multiple linear transformations?

Tags: manim

I'm trying to use `LinearTransformationScene`'s `apply_matrix` multiple times:

```
from manim import *

class LT(LinearTransformationScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            self,
            show_coordinates=True,
            leave_ghost_vectors=True,
        )

    def construct(self):
        P     = [[1, 1], [1, -1]];
        D     = [[2, 0], [0, 0.5]];
        P_inv = [[0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]];

        self.apply_matrix(P);
        self.wait();

        self.apply_matrix(D);
        self.wait();

        self.apply_matrix(P_inv);
        self.wait();
```

But I get this error: `submobjects must be of type VMobject`.

I'm hoping to create an animation that:

1. Applies the matrix `P`
2. Pauses briefly
3. Applies another matrix `D`
4. Pauses briefly again
5. And finally, applies the inverse of P, `P_inv`.

How do I accomplish this? There were similar questions posted, but no one posted about this specific error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These specialized `Scene` classes are unfortunately not very well maintained, this is a known issue. There is a simple workaround though: after calling `self.apply_matrix`, add

```
self.moving_mobjects = []
```

and the next application of `apply_matrix` will work as intended again.

Comment: Thanks! But it worked only after I added `self.moving_mobjects = []
` after `self.wait()` and not `self.apply_matrix`